# PHP - Ordenar o objeto por data sem a chave

Tags: php, array, laravel, classificação

Estou recebendo de uma API o seguinte objeto:

```
{
"30/01/2019": [
    {
        "type": "document",
        "filepath": "url",
        "recipients": [
            "Todos"
        ],
        "category": "Ata",
        "date": "30/01/2019"
    },
    {
        "type": "note",
        "note": "Note Example",
        "date": "30/01/2019"
    }
],
"12/01/2019": [
    {
        "type": "document",
        "filepath": "url",
        "recipients": [
            "Todos"
        ],
        "category": "Outra",
        "date": "12/01/2019"
    }
],
"31/01/2019": [
    {
        "type": "document",
        "filepath": "url",
        "recipients": [
            "604"
        ],
        "category": "Ata",
        "date": "31/01/2019"
    }
],
"15/01/2019": [
    {
        "type": "document",
        "filepath": "url",
        "recipients": [
            "604"
        ],
        "category": "Outra",
        "date": "15/01/2019"
    }
],
"01/02/2019": [
    {
        "type": "bill",
        "filepath":"url",
        "date": "01/02/2019",
        "status": 0
    }
]
}
```

Preciso ordená-lo pela data, que na verdade é a chave do array de objetos.

Alguém sabe como eu conseguiria ordenar esse objeto?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer assim:

//Em ordem Crescente

collect($array)->sortBy('date');

//Ou em ordem Decrescente

collect($array)->sortByDesc('date');